# Speed of Golang Vs Java

Tags: java, go

I have written a program in Java and equivalent in Go. My java program is taking around 5.95 seconds to execute while Go program is taking around 41.675789791 seconds. While speed of Go is comparable to C or C++ as it is compiled like C then Why this much of performance difference exists? Programs are as follows:

**Go Program**

```
package main


import (
    "math"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("vvalue is %v", testFun(10, 16666611, 1000000000))
}

func fun(x float64) float64 {
    return math.Pow(x, 2) - x
}

func testFun(first float64, second float64, times int) float64 {
    var i = 0
    var result float64 = 0
    var dx float64
    dx = (second - first) / float64(times)
    for ; i < times; i++ {
        result += fun(first + float64(i) * dx)
    }
    return result * dx
}
```

**Java Program**

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    double re = test.testFun(10, 16666611, 1000000000);
    System.out.println(re);
}

private double testFun(double first, double second, long times) {
    int i = 0;
    double result = 0;
    double dx = (second - first) / times;
    for (; i < times; i++) {
        result += fun(first + i * dx);
    }
    return result * dx;
}

private double fun(double v) {
    return Math.pow(v, 2) - v;
}
}
```

Comment: Java optimizes using a JIT (Just In Time) compiler, which means that it will generate machine code specifically targeted for the machine it's running on, so don't just assume that Java is slow(er).

Comment: Unless the majority of your program's execution time is spent calculating exponents, this is a wild goose chase. Write an actual program, benchmark it, profile to find the hot spots, optimize those, re-run benchmarks, rinse, repeat. Microbenchmarks like this are not indicative of any real-world scenario.

Answer (score 13):

*(With tips from above answers, I did more test, with an additional `C` version)*

On my linux machine, with times = **100000000**.

**Testing result:**

- When exponent = **2.4**

> ```
>  Java: result: 1.053906e+24, during: 7432 ms
>     C: result: 1.053906e+24, during: 5544 ms
>    Go: result: 1.053906e+24, during: 8.716807708s
> ```

- When exponent = **2**, still use `pow()` or `Pow()`.

> ```
>  Java: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 630 ms
>     C: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 852 ms
>    Go: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 3.336549272s
> ```

- When exponent = **2**, but use `x * x` instead.

> ```
>  Java: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 636 ms
>     C: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 340 ms
>    Go: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 115.491272ms
> ```

**Summary:**

- In general, `go` is really fast, according to the last test, faster than `Java`, or even `C`.
- But, `Java` really have a good `pow()` implementation, according to the first 2 test.

---

### Code

**Test.java:**

```
/**
 * Compile:
 *  javac Test.java
 * Run:
 *  java Test
 */ 
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    long startAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double re = test.testFun(10, 16666611, 100000000);
    long during = System.currentTimeMillis() - startAt;
        System.out.printf("%10s: result: %e, during: %d ms\n", "Java", re, during);
    }

    private double testFun(double first, double second, long times) {
        int i = 0;
        double result = 0;
        double dx = (second - first) / times;
        for (; i < times; i++) {
            result += fun(first + i * dx);
        }
        return result * dx;
    }

    private double fun(double v) {
        return v * v - v;
        // return Math.pow(v, 2) - v;
        // return Math.pow(v, 2.4) - v;
    }
}
```

**test.c:**

```
/**
 * compile with:
 *  gcc test.c -lm
 */
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double fun(double v) {
    return v * v - v;
    // return pow(v, 2) - v;
    // return pow(v, 2.4) - v;
}

double testFun(double first, double second, long times) {
    int i;
    double result = 0;
    double dx = (second - first) / times;
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        result += fun(first + i * dx);
    }
    return result * dx;
}

long long current_timestamp() {
    struct timeval te;
    gettimeofday(&te, NULL); // get current time
    long long milliseconds =
        te.tv_sec * 1000LL + te.tv_usec / 1000; // calculate milliseconds
    // printf("milliseconds: %lld\n", milliseconds);
    return milliseconds;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long long startAt = current_timestamp();
    double re = testFun(10, 16666611, 100000000);
    long long during = current_timestamp() - startAt;
    printf("%10s: result: %e, during: %lld ms\n", "C", re, during);
    return 0;
}
```

**test.go:**

```
/**
 * How to run:
 *  go run test.go
 */
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    startAt := time.Now()
    result := testFun(10, 16666611, 100000000)
    during := time.Since(startAt)
    fmt.Printf("%10s: result: %e, during: %v\n", "Go", result, during)

    _ = math.Pow
}

func fun(x float64) float64 {
    return x*x - x
    // return math.Pow(x, 2) - x
    // return math.Pow(x, 2.4) - x
}

func testFun(first float64, second float64, times int) float64 {
    var i = 0
    var result float64 = 0
    var dx float64
    dx = (second - first) / float64(times)
    for ; i < times; i++ {
        result += fun(first + float64(i)*dx)
    }
    return result * dx
}
```

**Compile:**

```
javac Test.java; gcc test.c -lm; go build test.go
```

**Run:**

```
java Test; ./a.out ; ./test
```

---

### @Update - C program with `-O2` or `-O3` option

As suggested by `Raffaello` in the comment, when compiling C program, could use `-O2` or `-O3` to further optimize the program.

And, following are the test result for `C` program:

- When exponent = **2.4**.

> ```
>             C: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 5805 ms
>  C with `-O2`: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 5324 ms
>  C with `-O3`: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 5326 ms
> ```

- When exponent = **2**, still use `pow()` or `Pow()`.

> ```
>             C: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 897 ms
>  C with `-O2`: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 119 ms
>  C with `-O3`: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 121 ms
> ```

- When exponent = **2**, but use `x * x` instead.

> ```
>             C: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 353 ms
>  C with `-O2`: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 122 ms
>  C with `-O3`: result: 1.543194e+21, during: 119 ms
> ```

**Summary** - (`-O2` and `-O3` option):

- With `-O2` and `-O3` option

  - When base is integer *(e.g 2)*, would make c program quicker, by several times.
  - When base is floating point number *(e.g 2.4)*, it's also quicker, but very minimal.
- Comparing between `-O2` and `-O3`, they are quite close in above tests.

Comment: Go is automatically inlining fun() and unrolling the core loop. Gcc might be. Explicitly using C11 inlining, -O3, and -funroll-all-loops would speed up C and offer a more accurate comparison. The multiplication by `dx` in the loop can also be replaced with iterative addition.

Comment: It's surprising to see C lose a Go compiler written in C.

Comment: You should have compiled the C code with `-o2` parameter for optimization (or even `-o3`). would be nice to have the updated benchmark result with the proper C compilation flag. :)

Comment: @Raffaello Thanks for the tip, indeed the `-O2` or `-O3` would speed up the C program above, I have updated the answer with result of additional tests. BTW, the options seems should be upper `O`, not lower.

Answer (score 10):

Don't translate from another language. Write the Go version of your program in Go. For example, `x*x - x`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    v := testFun(10, 16666611, 1000000000)
    since := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("value is %v\ntime is %v\n", v, since)
}

func fun(x float64) float64 {
    return x*x - x
}

func testFun(first float64, second float64, times int) float64 {
    sum := float64(0)
    dx := (second - first) / float64(times)
    for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
        sum += fun(first + float64(i)*dx)
    }
    return sum * dx
}
```

Output:

```
$ go version
go version devel +5c11480631 Fri Aug 10 20:02:31 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
$ go run speed.go
value is 1.543194272428967e+21
time is 1.011965238s
$
```

What results do you get?

Comment: "don't translate from other language" - Good answer! 

Comment: It means calculating x^n for large integer n in go requires own Power function implementation rather than using math.Pow function if n is not of float type?

Comment: well for that kind of example is the same for everylanguage. In that benchmark, actually is honest to use the same "math.Pow" function, instead of `x*x-x` expression. So it is irrelevant

Comment: Even when writing Java, why would somebody use `Math.pow` with exponent 2? This has nothing to do with translating from another language. This has everything to do with using a general function for a special case. The OP just got lucky that Java has some optimization for integer values in place. 
We could also compare `Math.pow(x, 2.5)` with `x * x * Math.sqrt(x)`. The latter might be faster in both languages.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that `math.Pow(x,y)` in Go actually does `x^y` without any optimization for integer values of `y` while `Math.pow(x,y)` simply does `x*x` for `y==2`. At least when replacing `pow` with a simple `x*x` in both programs I get 6.5 seconds for Java vs. 1.4 seconds for Go. Using `pow` instead I still get 6.5 seconds for Java while 29.4 seconds for Go.

Comment: It seems `math.Pow()` is slow in go, when both Java & Go use component `2.4`, go is a bit slower than Java, but when avoid `math.Pow()`, go is much faster than Java.

Comment: It means calculating x^n for large integer n in go requires own Power function implementation rather than using math.Pow function if n is not of float type?

Answer (score -2):

In theory, Go needs time to compile all source code at the beginning than its startup time will be slow but it will run fast when it finishes startup and executes command one by one. Executing time can be compared to C/C++. You can not compare them just in a few line of code, you will see the startup time will be affected a lot in a thousand files program.

Comment: go is compiled just like c/c++ so it does not compile all the source code at the beginning. you compile first and then run the executable